# Toggle active/inactive class angular from different component

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I have a parent component HeaderComponent with two children, `NavComponent` and `BurgerComponent`! At the moment, there is a class that toggles the active/inactive state of the burger when clicked on it! Below is the first image when the `BurgerComponent` is inactive, the second with an active `BurgerComponent` and `NavComponent` visible.

### The issue

The `NavComponent` is closed by a click on nav area, but I also need the `BurgerComponent` to go to the inactive state(image 1).

[image: The inactive Burger][image: Active burger with NavComponent visible]

What I have so far:

NavCompoent HTML with click event

```html
<nav class="nav-menu {{ menuStatus }}" (click)="collapseMenu($event)">
```

NavComponent TS:

```js
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

    title: string;
    closeMenu: boolean;
    @Output() sendTitle = new EventEmitter < string > ();
    @Output() menuClose = new EventEmitter<any>();
    @Input() menuStatus: boolean;

    active = false;
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    getText(event) {
        this.title = event.target.innerText;
        this.sendTitle.emit(this.title)
        console.log("title sent", this.title);
    }

    collapseMenu($event) {
        this.menuStatus = false;
        this.menuClose.emit(this.menuStatus);
    }
}
```

HeaderComponent HTML (this is the parent component)

```html
<header class="sticky">
    <div class="header-container">
        <div class="header-left">
            <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
            <app-burger (opened)="burgerStatus($event)" [menuCloseBurger]="menuClose"></app-burger>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<app-nav (sendTitle)="getTitle($event)" [menuStatus]="burger" (menuClose)="sendingMenuClose($event)"></app-nav>
```

Header Component TS:

```js
export class HeaderComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  route: string;
  pageTitle: string;
  burger: string;
  menuClose: string;

  constructor(location: Location, router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(val => {
        this.pageTitle = location.path();
        this.pageTitle = this.pageTitle.substring(1);
    });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pageTitle = this.route;
    console.log(this.pageTitle);
  }

  getTitle($event) {
    console.log(this.route);
    this.pageTitle = $event;
  }

  burgerStatus($event) {
    this.burger = $event;
    console.log($event);
  }

  sendingMenuClose($event) {
    this.menuClose = $event;
    console.log("menu close at parent", this.menuClose);
  }
}
```

BurgerComponent TS:

```js
export class BurgerComponent implements OnInit {
  active: boolean;
  @Output() opened = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() menuCloseBurger: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.active = false;
  } 

  onBurgerClicked() {
    this.active = !this.active;
    this.opened.emit(this.active);
  }
}
```

BurgerComponent HTML:

```html
<div class="burger-menu" [class.active]="active" (click)="onBurgerClicked()">
  <div class="burger-container">
    <div class="burger-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

collapseMenu() send a boolean value false, I need to get this into the BurgerCompnent class somehow so the value of that is false and the burger close. I am so close, I can't figure out the last step!

As per @PitchBlackCat's recommendation I have create a service NavStatusService!

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavStatusService {

  constructor() { }

   public readonly isNavCollapsed$ = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
}
```

I have implemented it in the BurgerComponent:

```js
  onBurgerClicked() {
    this.active = !this.active;
    this.state.isNavCollapsed$.emit(this.active);
  }
```

Now I am stuck as to how the communication between in the two component, Burger and Nav supposed to work!

Comment: Simply store your state in a service, and inject the service in all your components. That's what services are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate service to manage the shared variables.

You could try a framework like [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/) or create your own service along the lines of the example provided below.

Notice how the application-state.service has become the owner of the data that is shared between multiple components. This way, components that live in seperate parts of your layout can share data, whithout knowing about eachother.

*application-state.service*

```
export class ApplicationStateService implements OnInit {
  public isNavCollapsed: boolean = false;
}
```

*burger.component*

```
<button class="burger" [class.active]="!state.isNavCollapsed" (click)="onBurgerClicked()">

</button>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationStateService } from '../application-state.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-burger',
  templateUrl: './burger.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./burger.component.css']
})
export class BurgerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public state: ApplicationStateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onBurgerClicked() {
    this.state.isNavCollapsed = !this.state.isNavCollapsed;
  }

}
```

*nav.component*

```
<ul *ngIf="!state.isNavCollapsed">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>
    <button (click)="state.isNavCollapsed = true">close</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationStateService } from '../application-state.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public state: ApplicationStateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Check out [this example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-service-example) to see it in action

Comment: ...or simply act directly on `ApplicationStateService.active`. If you inject the service in every component, then `ApplicationStateService.active` will be available everywhere.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense theoretically but I am too much of a beginner to find a practical solution! Do you mind elaborating on your answer a bit? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer and provided an example The trick is to put the shared variable in a service. I hope this will help you finish your solution.